# Troubles with CABasicAnimation transform on CALayer

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-animation, calayer

I am trying to animate a transform on a CAGradientLayer, however no matter what I do, I can't seem to make the change happen. After this code runs, the layer is still not visible (i.e. scale.y is still 0.0f).

```
@implementation NickView

+(Class) layerClass {
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}

- (void) didMoveToWindow {    
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    CAGradientLayer* gLayer = (CAGradientLayer*)self.layer;

    [gLayer setColors:
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      (id) [UIColor blackColor].CGColor,
      (id) [UIColor redColor].CGColor,
      (id) [UIColor blackColor].CGColor,
      nil]];

    gLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    [self performSelector:@selector(doAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
}

- (void) doAnimation  {
    CABasicAnimation* a = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.y"];
    a.delegate = self;
    a.duration = 5.0f;
    a.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    [self.layer addAnimation:a forKey:@"anim"];
}
```

}

Does anyone know why this doesn't result in the scale.y of the layer being animated back to 1?

Comment: That is because `CALayer` doesn't have a property named `transform.scale.y`

Comment: @ZeusAlexander But it _is_ a perfectly valid key path for animating. Read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW1) again.

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird to cast self.layer to a gradient layer and then animate it afterwards? I thought you would add your own layer to it and reference it via an ivar. What happens if you set breakpoints in doAnimation and inspect the state? What happens if you animate some other property instead? Note: explicit animations will never change the actual value so after the animation the value will appear to jump back to its original state, is this what you are seeing?

Comment: I've tried this now with a sublayer, setting removedOnCompletion=NO as well as the fillMode to forward, yields same result. If I comment out the line in the first method where I set the transform explicitly and then change the animation to scale to 0.0f, I see the layer shrink down correctly. It's almost as if setting the transform manually is disabling all animations on the layer.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember that using a scale of 0 causes the layer to collapse to zero size. Try using a size of .001 instead of 0.